# I am having an issue with ASP .NET user controls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, user-controls

I have an issue currently that I can't resolve. I have a user control called "Dashboard" which then has the following markup, containing several subcontrols.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Dashboard.ascx.cs" Inherits="BlueSEQ.Controls.Dashboard.Dashboard" %>
<%@ Register src="Administrator.ascx" tagname="Administrator" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="Provider.ascx" tagname="Provider" tagprefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register src="User.ascx" tagname="User" tagprefix="uc3" %>

<% if (isAdministrator)
{ %>
<uc1:Administrator ID="Administrator1" runat="server" />
<% }
else if (isProvider)
{  %>
<uc2:Provider ID="Provider1" runat="server" />
<% }
else
{  %>
<uc3:User ID="User1" runat="server" />
<% } %>
```

As you can see, I want it to display some controls or other controls depending on some conditions. However, all of these controls' "Load" event get triggered, even if they are not used.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can help it, try to avoid having conditional logic in your markup.  It could make the views somewhat more difficult to understand for designers (if you're working with designers) and more difficult to find and refactor this code in the future.

You should also take a look at [ASP.NET MVC: Avoiding Tag Soup](http://wekeroad.com/2008/07/27/asp-net-mvc-avoiding-tag-soup/).  Although it's ASP.NET MVC, it's still a good example of how adding logic to your views can quickly make them very difficult and unpleasant to maintain (initial example).

---

You could use the technique described here: How to: [Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Your markup would look something like this.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder id="MyPlaceholder" />
```

and your codebehind would have something along the lines of

```
private void InitSection()
{
    Control c;

    if( isAdministrator )
        c = Page.LoadControl("~\Administrator.ascx")
    else if( isProvider )
        c = Page.LoadControl("~\Provider.ascx") 
    else
        c = Page.LoadControl("~\User.ascx");

    MyPlaceholder.Controlls.Add(c);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The ideal way to do this is to set up asp.net role provider and use a LoginView control, something along the lines of the code below. LoginView only loads the appropriate content.

```
<asp:LoginView runat="server">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
       <uc1:User ID="User" runat="server" />
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <RoleGroups>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Administrator">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:Administrator ID="Administrator1" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
        <asp:RoleGroup Roles="Provider">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <uc1:Provider ID="Provider" runat="server" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:RoleGroup>
    </RoleGroups>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to Load the control on a specific condition instead, so try to set `visible/invisible` with the usercontrol, that's a much better approach

```
<% if (isAdministrator)
{ %>
Page.LoadControl(("~\Administrator1.ascx");
<% }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a MultiView control?
[MultiView on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227440%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I think `MultiView` would still load all of the controls and run at least some of the events on them.